# Magento2: Override default phtml file without create custom theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides

I'm trying to override customer's login.phtml file and I am able to manage the override by creating custom theme `Tracks/customtheme`, also I put the .phtml file in my custom theme like this `/app/design/frontend/Tracks/customtheme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml` and it is working properly.

My question is, there is a blank folder named Magento in `/app/design/` directory after downloading M2. So, why we can't override .phtml file like this `/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml`? Any suggestion should be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For override login.phtml file at module level you need to create customer_account_login.xml file to override and using setTemplate method we need to set our customm module file path.

Check link, [How to override Customer login.phtml file](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-override-customer-form-login-phtml-file-to-custom-module-in-magento-2/)

```
<action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Rbj_Customer::form/login.phtml</argument>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But if i want to override phtml file not as module level then creating custom theme is compulsory in M2?
For ex if i want to override luma theme's login.phtml file then it's not working if i put that file in Magento namespace like following directory. Am i right? /app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

Comment: Hi Raj, If you want to override file in theme level, you must create new theme. if you want to change directly in luma theme you need to changes directly inside vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Customer/templates

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `.phtml` file in Magento directory under `app/design/frontend` directory. However, you have to associate the same `.phtml` file in `Magento/CustomTheme` module configuration. Still, it is not recommended to use the default Magento namespace for the custom theme, as it is out of the Magento conventions. So, you should create your own namespace.

Which you did already.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
You can use the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::customer/login.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Method 2:**
As action is depreciated you can use the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login" template="Vendor_Module::customer/login.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```